# Foreach Loop with Jquery Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, counter

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="single-count_contain">
<div class="less"><img src="img/single_arrow_left.png"></div>
<div class="theCount">1</div>
<div class="add"><img src="img/single_arrow_right.png"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 1;

$(".add").click(function(){

counter++;

$(this).closest(".single-count_contain").find(".theCount").text(counter);

});


$(".less").click(function(){

 counter--;

$(this).closest(".single-count_contain").find(".theCount").text(counter);

});
```

This works as intended, increment and decrement my counter variable. But i need to use it in a foreach loop.

How can i have the same variable, but different results in each counter generated but the foreach loop?

Thank you!

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Do you have multiple `single-count_contain` elements and want to update the count for each one independently?

Comment: Yes, that! I want to update each one individually, since i have many with the same information, and the same variable. When i try to update other, the information start where the last update finnish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the count element will always contain a value, the simplest way to do this would be to read the text of the count element, parse it to integer and update it.

e.g.

```js
$(".add").click(function() {

  var $count = $(this).closest(".single-count_contain").find(".theCount");
  $count.text(parseInt($count.text()) + 1);

});

$(".less").click(function() {

  var $count = $(this).closest(".single-count_contain").find(".theCount");
  $count.text(parseInt($count.text()) - 1);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="single-count_contain">
  <div class="less"><img src="img/single_arrow_left.png"></div>
  <div class="theCount">1</div>
  <div class="add"><img src="img/single_arrow_right.png"></div>
</div>

<div class="single-count_contain">
  <div class="less"><img src="img/single_arrow_left.png"></div>
  <div class="theCount">1</div>
  <div class="add"><img src="img/single_arrow_right.png"></div>
</div>
```

You could also use the [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function to select the count element.

e.g.

```
var $count = $(this).siblings(".theCount");
```

**Update**

To update the data-counter value you could do this:

```
var count = parseInt($count.text()) + 1;
$count.text(count).data("counter", count);
```

**Another solution**

```js
$(".single-count_contain").each(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  
  $(this).on("click", ".less,.add", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less"))
      counter--;
    else
      counter++;

    $(this).siblings(".theCount").text(counter).data("counter", counter);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="single-count_contain">
  <div class="less"><img src="img/single_arrow_left.png"></div>
  <div class="theCount">1</div>
  <div class="add"><img src="img/single_arrow_right.png"></div>
</div>

<div class="single-count_contain">
  <div class="less"><img src="img/single_arrow_left.png"></div>
  <div class="theCount">1</div>
  <div class="add"><img src="img/single_arrow_right.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This will do :).

Comment: Another question, if possible, i want to also have a data-counter in the same div. Like "<div class="theCount" data-counter="1">1</div>. How can i update this data counter, at the same time i update the other? Thank you. Best regards!

Comment: Updated answer with a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you for all the solutions, you rock! :). Just one last question i promise. It's possible to lets say to have <div class="theCount" data-counter="1">1</div> and <div class="value">10</div>, and each time i increment or decrement, i get the value change also. Like 10 - 20 - 30 - 40, and if i decrement, to have 30 - 20 - 10. Following your explanation i could change the value, but if i get 20, i will get 40 after, and 80 after that. I can't just increment by keeping the first value. Any idea? :)

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand but it sounds like `value` is constant for each counter? If so you could just get the text of the `.value` element, parseInt it and increment/decrement by that.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I can increment/decrement that value. But since i'm saying that i'm incrementing/decrementing that text(), after the value change from 10 to 20, since 10x2(count) = 20. The new value will be 20. For that reason if i multiply for the count again, it will be 20x3(count) and not 10x3(count).  Don't know if it's possible to this, since i'm only changing text. Nevertheless i created a new hidden value, and multiply always for that one, since this new default don't change. If you have a better approach, just let me know, if possible :).